# split CSV seperated data into multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have data like this in excel, Column Animal No and Clinical Signs have text data seperated by comma.

Input

[image: Group Animal No Phase Clinical Signs Day G1 R1 Predose Normal 1 G1 R1 Postdose Normal 1 G2 R2,R3,R4 Predose Normal 1 G2 R2,R3,R4 Postdose Hypoactivity, Lethargy 1]

i wanted to get the output like this i dont want to use power pivot as the results will be pasted as query table. I want vba code to do the same and paste it in the same sheet

[image: preferred output]

Comment: What code do you have? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You should split this into steps - get the last row, loop the data, use `Split` on the two CSV sets of data, and loop the resulting arrays to get data that can then be output to the worksheet.

Comment: BTW, Power Query can put the result in the same sheet.

Comment: braX thanks for the reply, i am learning vba coding for my routine excel sheets. i am a starter i have code which splits only one column say Animal No in the example. but i want to use it for two column. Plz help

Comment: Storax, power query is pasting cells as a table Which i am not able to create a string concatenated pivot table. I wanted the data to be arranged normally without any power query. I will be using this in Userform also

Comment: Yes, right, you will get a table. What is the problem with that? I consider this as an advantage.

Comment: i was not able to use this =CONCATENATEX(Table1,Table1[Day],",") function in the pivot table. It shows formula is correct but when i transfer that to values coloumn it is not getting updated

Comment: I was talking about Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 2 To r
        a = Split(vDB(i, 2), ",")
        b = Split(vDB(i, 4), ",")
        For j = 0 To UBound(a)
            For k = 0 To UBound(b)
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
                vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
                vR(2, n) = Trim(a(j))
                vR(3, n) = vDB(i, 3)
                vR(4, n) = Trim(b(k))
                vR(5, n) = vDB(i, 5)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    With Ws
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: @MarrisaiSudheer, If it works for you. Please accept the answer.